# Returning episode name of episode with highest rating on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I'm keeping track of South Park episodes, just for personal fun really, including my personal ratings for each episode and the iMDB average rating of each episode, and a separate spreadsheet for displaying stats like 'average rating per season', '% of episodes rated per season' and so on, and among those is the highest/lowest rated episode per season, each by me and by iMDB on average, and that is where I am having trouble automatically getting the right output.

I've used queries only one time before for a separate project, but queries do not seem to work this time around, although I admittedly do not know what I'm doing there.

Original sheet with individual columns for season no, episode no, episode title, personal rating, and iMDB average rating (hidden columns are private):
[image]

Stats sheet with columns for season no, % of episodes rated, count of episodes rated, amount of episodes, average personal rating, average iMDB rating, highest & lowest rated episode per my rating, and highest & lowest rated episode per average iMDB rating (all per season), plus my own attempt at using a query to get the desired value for the first season:
[image]

What I want it to return is the episode names for the "highest & lowest rated episode per my rating, and highest & lowest rated episode per average iMDB rating" parts of the stats sheet, e.g. for season 5, I want it to display "Scott Tenorman Must D**" (unsure how strict censorship is on this site, but I don't want to risk anything) for the "Best iMDB" column as it has the highest iMDB rating average for the season. I'm aware that I might have extra trouble with this where there are multiple episodes with the same highest rating and so on.

Apologies for my potentially poor wording or under/overexplaining. This is the first time I've posted here and I'm kind of a noob with Google Sheets formulas and whatnot. I'd be happy to elaborate if asked.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Yep, you'll get a lot further sharing the actual data and not a screenshot.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I'll bare all that in mind next time I ask about anything Excel/Google Sheets related.

Answer (score 0):

*remove the single quotes `'` in your formula & try as `season number` & `your rating` **are numbers** & quotes placed around them will convert them to text :*

```js
=query('South Park'!A:D,"select C Where A = "&A3&" and D = "&maxifs('South Park'!D:D,'South Park'!A:A,A3)&" limit 1",0)
```

***Alternate formula***:

```js
=+sort(filter('South Park'!C:D,'South Park'!A:A=A3),2,0)
```

- *this part `filter('South Park'!C:D,'South Park'!A:A=A3)` filters all the **1st** season names + rating in 2 columns → I am sorting (highest to lowest) the output obtained in the first step by column_2(which would be rating) → Once sort is done I am restricting the array to single first cell (using `+`); this is similar to how you used `limit 1` parameter in your query formula version*

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain the alternate formula please? I've worked it out well enough to use it for both the highest of my rating and the iMDB rating, but not for the lowest of each of those.

Comment: added a bit of explanation wrt., alternate formula. to sort lowest to highest replace this part of the formula `,2,0)` with `,2,1)`